# How can I automate adding a Return URI to the Google API Oauth Credentials

Tags: google-oauth, google-developers-console

Is there a Google SDK for actually adding the return URIs to OAuth credentials? Since I can't specify wildcard I can't make one that fits all.  What I'm trying to achieve is a development deployment pipeline for our old monolithic app that uses Google Login. I need to specify the return URI for the application but the deployment I'm working on determines the subdomain of the deployment at the time of build. The general idea is to allow developers project branch names to be subdomains that route to their deployed K8S test image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for adding redirect uri to the Google Oauth credentials.   You need to set up your projects manually.